Temporal deictic expressions and the latest reference point
I was reading the lectures of Charles Fillmore on temporal deixis, and he started talking about expressions like “in a [non-calendar time unit]”
What he didn’t talk about (in this type of expressions) is when there is a previously defined reference point (say:

After he ate dinner he went to sleep in an hour.)

Do “in an hour” and similar statements always rely on the last defined reference point?

Can you think of an example where it doesn’t?  It’s sort of hard to say “always”, as it implies a review of all possible English sentences.

@Xanne I obviously can’t, I mean typically, when we have such a structure, do we assume that this is the case

One has to be careful to be idiomatic. 'After he ate dinner he went to sleep in an hour' sounds decidedly unnatural; 'he ate dinner – and he was asleep within the hour', 'after he ate dinner, he fell asleep in less than an hour', 'he took just an hour to fall asleep after eating dinner', or perhaps 'He ate dinner, after which he retired in less than an hour' sound more likely.

@EdwinAshworth thanks! in these cases (where it’s idiomatically english, and generally) do we think of the last reference point as the anchor of the deictic statements?

I'm trying to come up with a counter-example. What are other examples of similar  temporal deictic expressions like 'in a [non-calendar time unit]'? Some are notionally anchored 'His temper would flare up in a moment.' [on occasions where he felt provoked]. But obviously with 'After the hamster ate the poison, it lived only a few hours' has a definite anchor.

@EdwinAshworth I was mostly thinking of when we have:  a reference points + a verb/action that it anchors + the deictic expression

Deictic expressions themselves need an anchor, surely.  I can only think of a counterexample to your proposal where there are 2 possible anchors, one of which would make no sense as the anchor for the proposed temporal expression. But one would rephrase in the examples I've come up with.

@EdwinAshworth Does the anchor need to be explicitly mentioned? And what are the ones that don’t make sense and ones that are rephrased? (Sorry if I’m slow in getting the matter, I’m learning deixis for the first time)

(1) 'Does “in an hour” (or similar statements) always rely on the last defined reference point?'
No:

In the war, when everyone had to do his or her duty, he quickly enlisted.

Here, the anchor '[In] the war' (Think 'When war broke out'; the implication is early during the war) makes sense, the parenthetical being a descriptor of a facet of the war (as well as a part-reason for the following independent clause).
Compare the rewrite

In the war, he quickly enlisted. This was a time when everyone had to do his or her duty.

This example works in either version.
The examples

At long last, Elizabeth finished her preparation in the classroom. She arrived home one hour later. Two hours later, she was fast asleep.
At long last, Elizabeth finished her preparation in the classroom. She arrived home one hour later; two hours later, she was fast asleep.
At long last, Elizabeth finished her preparation in the classroom. She arrived home one hour later, and two hours later, she was fast asleep.

are ambiguous.
Taking (in hours and idealising to avoid fractions)

T₀ = time of finishing work
T₁ = time of arrival at home
T₂ = time of getting to sleep (or negligibly after this time)

we know that T₁ = T₀ + 1
but does          T₂ = T₀ + 2 or T₁ + 2?
I'd say that the default reading is in each case that the anchor for the final statement is the finishing of work, not the arrival at home (which goes against the 'proximity' rule of thumb.) T₂ = T₀ + 2.  I'd also say that the weight of default increases as we proceed down the variants as listed. But even then, I'd personally rephrase slightly to make absolutely unambiguous, say with

At long last, Elizabeth finished her preparation in the classroom. She arrived home one hour later, and in a further hour, she was fast asleep.

(My style here could doubtless be bettered.)
So, in summary, a temporal expression does not always refer to the nearest preceding event / time specification, and indeed ambiguity can thus arise, if illogicality does not rule out one potential reading.
..........................
(2)  'Does the anchor need to be explicitly mentioned?'
Again, arguably no:
As mentioned,

[He was not an easy man.] His temper could flare up in a moment.

has a suppressed/notional [perhaps on occasions where he felt provoked, or after the accident] anchor (I'm using the word 'anchor' with the dictionary definition of something like 'referent/trigger point'; I know CGEL use it, and perhaps use a tighter stipulative definition.) But this is a fixed-phrase usage of 'in a moment' meaning 'instantaneously' rather than 'in a couple of seconds'.
However, if using temporals in the sense of 'minutes before' / 'a short time later' / 'within the hour' / 'not long afterwards' / 'at the time' / ..., it is an error in communication if a prior anchor is not provided (explicitly, by the speaker or speaker). It's different when similar phrases are used to describe lengths of time taken for an achievement (eg He can get up, shower, make and eat breakfast, read his daily reading, and drive to the station in under an hour'.
..........................
But my reading of

What he didn’t talk about (in this type of expressions[sic]) is when
there is a previously defined reference point

demands
'What he did talk about (in this type of expression) is when
there is no previously defined reference point.'
This is either incorrect, or Fillmore provided other examples in addition to 'He went to sleep in an hour.' (? – this sounds rather unnatural. Can you give [other?] actual examples from Fillmore?)

Ok, thanks! Is there a way to determine wether the deictic center is the present moment or the previously mentioned reference point in the structure I’ve talked about (reference point + action + deictic expression)? And can you please elaborate on this statement: “ I can only think of a counterexample to your proposal where there are 2 possible anchors, one of which would make no sense as the anchor for the proposed temporal expression. But one would rephrase in the examples I've come up with.”

(1) Just as 'It is clearly desirable [though not mandatory] that an anaphoric or cataphoric pronoun should be placed as near as the construction allows to the noun or noun phrase to which it refers. And [certainly] in such a manner that there is no risk of ambiguity' [[Burchfield, New Fowler] (https://www.grammar.com/antecedents-placement-of-pronouns), nearby anchors are best. _But if the nearest candidate would not make sense, it must be by-passed. (2)  I can't find a 'counterexample' that doesn't sound ridiculous! // Please address my last sentence in the answer above.

if you mean examples from Fillmore, then I didn’t get this example from him, this is an example I came up with, which is different from the example he gave, the example he gave is: “ Thus, if I say "I did it in a hour" the meaning is that it took me an hour to do it, and that I finished doing it”

I suspected he wouldn't offer 'After he ate dinner he went to sleep in an hour.', which i find unnatural-sounding. // Note that, as I've now emphasised in the  answer, 'I did it in an hour' lacks an anchor (as far as we know) and thus must merely speak of time taken not T₀ + 1. It would be different with 'I was surprised how easy it was; I started at 11:00 am, and I did it in an hour.'

I see, thanks for your patience. So overall, deictic expressions typically refer to the closest clearly defined reference point unless there’s ambiguity or other context that shifts the meaning. And in the case of using “now” as an anchor, it would require an explicit definition, correct?

(1) Typically, but not categorically (and note that ambiguity is an unwanted and best-avoided result rather than the helpful direction/clarification 'other context that shifts the meaning' is). (2) In conversation, 'now' is often implied ... at the time of speaking. "Could you take the bins out in the morning, please, Jim./?"

Thanks Mr. Ashworth, finally, about “now”, when we have a previously defined anchor in the sentence, “now” stops being an anchor because It isn’t necessary to the sentence, am I correct?

That depends on the sentence. 'The war in the Ukraine has allegedly lasted from 2014 until now; and judging from hardened attitudes, it will not now be over in a few weeks' obviously takes 'the few weeks' from  T₁ (now) not T₀ . But 'The war in the Ukraine allegedly began in 2014, making this a duration now of 10 years; it will probably last longer than the Mexican War of Independence' obviously refers to the total time, from T₀. But not quite the same example, I admit ... this is why I was hoping for some more examples from Fillmore.

I believe the second example doesn’t have a second anchor, right? Cause that’s what I’m trying to research. you’ve actually answered a previous question of mine, which got me interested in deixis, here’s your answer: “There's an implicit 'from/at the time just mentioned/defined/implied' in the use of temporal expressions like 'in the few months before', '7 years later', 'for seven years [when used this way]', 'present / then / now' (as in 'the then Chancellor'), 'for the following year' ... and sequencing adverbs like 'later', 'next', 'former'. A (temporal) deictic centre”
